# how to print values from a python list in pairs without printing already printed index values

Tags: python, list, indexing, printing

Python list `len` will always be even numbered; however, the len will vary at times. I want to print the index values in pairs without printing already printed index values. For example, if there are 6 indexes in the list or if the list has `len = 6`, I want to print

```
index 1 index 2
index 3 index 4
index 5 index 6
```

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

for i in range(len(list)):
    print(list[i], list[i+1])
```

output:

```
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5
6 6
```

desired output:

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

I've been pounding my head on this simple 'problem'. Please help.

Comment: Note, you can pass a step size to [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range).

Comment: `range(0, len(list), 2)`

Comment: umm...i feel really dumb haha. Thank you for that. I fixed it. for i in range(0, len(list), 2):
    print(list[i], list[i+1])

Comment: `for i, j in zip(list[::2], list[1::2]): print(i, j)`

Answer (score 0):

`range()` takes either one, two or three arguments, which is `end`, `start, end`, or `start, end, step`. You can use that here:

```py
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

for i in range(0, len(list), 2):
    print(list[i], list[i+1])
```

Output:

```py
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

Comment: Thank you too! I was just missing the step.

Comment: @Irvs if this answer has solved your problem you can consider accepting it.