# adding numbers two at a time in a list (python)

Tags: python, arrays, sum

```
list1=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
for x in range(len(list1)):
 print("{}+{}".format(list1[x],list1[x+1]))
 print(list1[x]+list1[x+1])
```

this is giving me 1+2=3, 2+3=5, 3+4=7, 4+5=9, 5+6=11.
what I want as an out put is : 1+2=3, 3+4=7, 5+6=11

Comment: Add a step of 2 to your range

Comment: The third argument to `range` is a step which decides how much `x` gets incremented by each loop.

Comment: Exactly the same problem: [how to print values from a python list in pairs without printing already printed index values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75673423/how-to-print-values-from-a-python-list-in-pairs-without-printing-already-printed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list1=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
for x in range(0,len(list1)-1,2):
    print("{}+{}={}".format(list1[x],list1[x+1],(list1[x]+list1[x+1])))
```

OUTPUT

1+2=3

3+4=7

5+6=11

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is go through the list in pairs, so change the step argument of `range()` to `2`:

```
list1=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
for x in range(0, len(list1)-1, 2):
  print("{}+{}".format(list1[x],list1[x+1]))
  print(list1[x]+list1[x+1])
```

See the [`range()` function documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#func-range) for more.

Comment: You can also make the print statement more readable by using:
print(f"{list[x]}+{list[x+1]} = {list[x] + list[x+1]}") instead of using format